# Android: Character encoding raw resource files

Tags: android, html, character-encoding, webview

I'm in the process of translating one of my apps to Spanish, and I'm having a character encoding problem with a raw HTML file I'm sticking into a WebView. I have the spanish translation of the file in my raw-es folder, and I'm reading it in with the following function:

```
private CharSequence getHtmlText(Activity activity) {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.help), "utf-8"));
            String line;
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) buffer.append(line).append('\n');
            return buffer;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "";
        } finally {
            closeStream(in);
        }
    }
```

But everywhere there is a spanish character in the file, there is a diamond with a question mark inside of it when I run the app, and look at the activity that displays the HTML. I'm using the following to load the text into the WebView:

```
mWebView.loadData(text, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

I originally created the file in Microsoft Word, so I'm sure there is some sort of character encoding issue going on, but I'm not really sure how to fix it, and a Google search isn't helping. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you specify UTF-8 as the encoding when you saved the file? (In Word 2003, if you save a document as HTML, there is an option to specify the character encoding, but it's hard to find. In the upper right of the file dialog, there's a "Tools Menu". One of its entries is "Web Options". One of the tabs in that dialog is "Character Encoding." Other versions of Word may have different ways to get to that setting.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't use loadData.  Use loadDataWithBaseURL instead.  You would say:

```
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL( null, text, "text/html", "utf-8", null );
```

Comment: This save me a lot of time. This should be marked as an answer. Thanks rglovejoy...

Comment: i have to say people can lose a lot of time looking for this in other questions here on SO about the same thing, only in this answer i found a true solution to spanish encoding. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a French translation where diamond symbols with question marks were appearing in place of certain characters, including those which I had escaped.  I got around it by opening file properties in Eclipse and changing the encoding to "ISO-8859-1".  Don't know if this would work for Spanish though.